# How to load list_item_event.xml in Android ListView?

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I'm trying to populate a ListView in my Android app. For this I'm writing an adapter in which I now want to inflate a list_item_event.xml file:

```
public PaymentItemListAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    EventItem rowItem = (EventItem) getItem(position);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_event);
}
```

The list_item_event.xml file exists, but the code above, results in an error saying: `cannot resolve symbol: 'list_item_event'.`.

Does anybody know what I might be doing wrong here? All tips are welcome!

[EDIT]
As suggested, I imported the wrong R. The same line now still gives me an error though;
`cannot resolve method 'inflate(int)'`. Any idea whats wrong there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably imported `android.R` file instead of `your.package.name.R`

Comment: I just now see that altough I didn't import android.R, I did import the wrong R (`import android.support.v7.appcompat.R;`). This leaves one question open though. It still says that it cannot resolve 'method inflate', even though I correctly import it (`import android.view.LayoutInflater;`) and set it to `inflater`. Any idea what could go wrong there?

Comment: Change `convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_event);` to `convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_event,null);`

Answer (score 1):

Try Changing,

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_event);
```

to this:

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_event,null);
```

This will workout.

Answer (score 1):

Use a valid type signature for inflate and check if the view is being recycled.

```
if (convertView == null)
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_event, parent, false);
```